# How to download minecraft for Linux

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to download Minecraft at minecraft.net. It says please
download Java (Please use Oracles JVM). What does that mean?
If I have that installed and I have minecraft.jar file installed, what
do I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

If you want the latest version of java (Java 8)
Then type in terminal this:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After you installed it press right click on it (The Minecraft.jar) then "Open with" after that you choose what version you want Java 8 or Java 7

Comment: He doesn't need the JDk, only the JRE.